# IE8 Height 100% Bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Has anyone heard of a bug that occurs with IE8 when applying height as a percentage to the html and body using CSS? I'm seeing a white background when a tile pattern should be applied.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #666;
    background-image: url('../images/body/bg_pattern.gif');
}
```

Comment: Personally, I need more details. A link to a live page would be awesome, or a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) example showing the bug.

Comment: Let me rephrase that comment: [there is nothing wrong](http://jsbin.com/ewupe3) with the code you posted in IE8. More context needed!

Answer (score 3):

IE8 interprets the height element closer to the standards than IE7 did. The statement

`Height: 100%

Is pretty much ignored. Percentage heights are based upon the height of their parent element. If the parent element doesn't have an explicit height, the percentage is ignored and set to Auto. You can see more about this on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property).

If the page you are displaying is empty, body will have a height of 0 and you will see the default background.

Comment: So what is the parent of html and body? The page has content so the height shouldn't be 0.

Comment: @Julian Moors, there is no parent. Are you floating your child elements? That can also cause this problem. Also, do you need to add  repeat-x and repeat-y to your background?

Comment: I'm expecting the pattern to repeat along both axes using default behaviour.

Comment: @Julian, sorry, had a brain fart. You're right, the background should repeat along both axes. Are you floating the child elements though? That can cause the parent elements to not have any height which is what I think the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the generated `height:0` when you're floating the child elements, set

```
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
```

on the parent.