# Height=100% is not applying with iframe in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with height of iframe in jsp.

When I use `height="100%"` it's not working, but when I use `height ="400px"` it's working. It's happening only in IE  when I change to the  Browser Mode:IE8 and the Document Mode: IE8 standards.

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: May be duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772396/ie8-height-100-bug